# Issue with compiling example code

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2

I'm trying to compile **[this](http://lists.apple.com/archives/mac-opengl/2009/Oct/msg00073.html)** sample code with XCode 4.2b, here's how my project looks like:

[image]

Application type: Command Line Tool. When I'm trying to build the project, I get the following list of errors:[image]

I suppose that I haven't added some frameworks to the project, though I don't know what frameworks should be added...

Comment: FYI, Xcode 4.2 is still under NDA and discussing it publicly could get you booted out of Apple's ADC program (meaning you won't be able to sell on the App Store either). Your problem doesn't seem to be 4.2-specific, so you might want to remove references to it being 4.2 (and probably not post pictures of it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The imported files probably contain Objective C code, but you're using the C compiler.

Change the file extension of `main.c` to `main.m`.

Comment: Y're right, though it can't find create_single_kernel_helper now, but I think I will manage to solve this problem...